# PHP error message - Undefined variable: db in LINE 6 and Fatal error: Call to a member function connect() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been getting these two error messages. my code is

```
public function __construct() {

        $db->connect();

    }

    function connect() {

        return  new mysqli('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_NAME);


    }
```

Does anyone know what my issue is. i am still very new to PHP so sorry if this is a stupid question.

my DB_USER ,DB_PASS, DB_NAME are saved in my config file

Comment: I've worked out the first error i had -> instead of  = but i am still getting  a Fatal error: Call to undefined function connect() in

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$this`  -

```
$this->db->connect();
```

`$db` supposed to be a member variable of that class. You can' access `$db` like that unless you have passed it to the function like -

```
function your_function($db) {
```

To access the member variables `$this` pointer is used, which points to the current instance.

Comment: thank you. tbh i've been trying to use a old open source DB classed that used mysql not mysqli- and just had loads of problems. so think i am going to have to write it all out myself

Comment: That will be better to undrstand.

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know a good up to date tutorial? my goal is to build a class that connects to the database - using prepared statements  inserts - updates - selects- all in a general way so the class can be used in multiple projects. then i want to create two custom classes that call on the methods of the db class  to insert /update/select with the unique queries for this application.

  i've found a few but any recommendation from someone who knows abit more about what there doing. would be greate